# Does the Emperor achievement counter reset when you save and load the game?

Tags: achievements, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

The Emperor achievement says:

> You have killed over two thousand units in a single session. You are a legend to both allies and enemies.

Does that mean single instance of running the Age of Empires? Or a single game? What exactly resets the counter?

Answer (score 1):

As 

[this](https://www.reddit.com/r/aoe2/comments/3wmxq4/finally_unlocked_the_emperor_achievement_in_a_3/) ("*finally unlocked the Emperor achievement in a 3 hour game*")

and 

[this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/0/648814395847603693/) (first comment: "*I've done it on a +2:30h hour game*")

thread suggest - and no allegations against the OP's for being silly are to be found in both threads - I assume it has to be done in a single game.